# node-red-dashboard - angularJs round value up or down - minutes to hour conversion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-red

I've an input number that is the total minutes i.e. 59870

this is the value show in a format of  hh:mm

```
{{ (msg.payload / 60|number:0)-1 }} : {{msg.payload % 60 | number:0 }}
```

thta will output

> 998:50

but actually it should be 997 hours.

How can I say to angular to round up or down?

these are the version info:

```
15 Jun 17:18:40 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5
15 Jun 17:18:40 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.11.2
15 Jun 17:18:40 - [info] Linux 4.15.0-2-amd64 x64 LE
15 Jun 17:18:40 - [info] Loading palette nodes
15 Jun 17:18:41 - [info] Dashboard version 2.6.2 started at /ui
```

Comment: Well, i tryed to replicate the  situation in this pen https://codepen.io/FederalCircle/pen/eKGRZy but its working there. What is the angular version you are using?

Comment: Alyson, node-red still uses Angular 2

Comment: Personally, I would probably use the `moment` node to format the payload before sending it to `ui_template`